# Test passing locally but failing in gitlab pipeling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I wrote some tests, which pass locally, but fail in the pipeline.

Here's the test:

```
async displaysMachineTypeWhenOtherMachineIsSelected () {
      const { asFragment } = render(
        FunctionsFactory.componentFactory({ fetchedState: { machine: mockedMachineState } }),
  );

  // Functions is an object. It's used in other tests and they all pass
  await Functions.selectMachineState1();

  Functions.clickEditText();

  await Functions.clickOnSelect(DetailsNames.Category);

  screen.getByText('Other machine').click();

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText(DetailsLabels.MachineType)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  expect(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).length).toEqual(10);

  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
}

it(
  'should display machine type dropdown when other machine is selected',
  displaysMachineTypeWhenOtherMachineIsSelected,
);
```

And as I said, it passes locally, but fails in the gitlab pipeline.

Error from gitlab:

```
  ● States › Testing machine view › Testing behavior › should display machine type dropdown when other machine is selected
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
      64 |         machineBehavior(sharedArgs);
      65 |
    > 66 |       it(
         |       ^
      67 |         'should display machine type dropdown when other machine is selected',
      68 |         displaysMachineTypeWhenOtherMachineIsSelected,
      69 |       );
      at components/pages/states/tests/States.test.tsx:66:7
      at components/pages/states/tests/States.test.tsx:62:5
      at components/pages/states/tests/States.test.tsx:49:3
      at Object.<anonymous> (components/pages/states/tests/States.test.tsx:25:1)
  ● States › Testing machine view › Testing behavior › should return to machine view on Cancel click
    expect(received).toMatchSnapshot()
    Snapshot name: `States Testing machine view Testing behavior should return to machine view on Cancel click 1`
    - Snapshot  - 1
    + Received  + 0
    @@ -782,11 +782,10 @@
                            Layers
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                          class="ant-tabs-ink-bar ant-tabs-ink-bar-animated"
    -                     style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="ant-tabs-nav-operations ant-tabs-nav-operations-hidden"
      85 |
      86 |       Functions.checkIfLabelsArePresent(machineLabels);
    > 87 |       expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
         |                            ^
      88 |     },
      89 |   };
      90 | };
      at Object.returnsToMachineViewOnCancelClick (components/pages/states/tests/testFunctions/machine-view/machineView.ts:87:28)
 › 1 snapshot failed.
```

dependencies from `package.json`:

```
"jest": "^27.0.5",
"babel-jest": "^27.0.5",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
"jest-cli": "^27.0.5",
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?